# Traefik - proxy to backend with path

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

i need to proxy `http://www.example.com/foo` to `http://<backend>/bar`, with nginx i have this configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    client_max_body_size 2048M;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location /foo {
        proxy_pass      http://container_name/bar/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

I would convert this to traefik. there my compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 traefik:
   image: traefik:1.7.3-alpine
   command: --api --docker
   ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   labels:
    - traefik.enable=false

 webapp:
   ...
   ...
   labels:
    - traefik.backend=bar
    - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com;Path:/foo/
    - traefik.port=80
```

is there a way to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like that using ReplacePathRegex for the frontend rule (no need to do anything on backend):

```
PathPrefix:/foo;ReplacePathRegex:^/foo(.*) /bar$$1
```

Comment: I suppose that the answer is correct, but have an error when make `up -d` : `ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "labels" option in service "webapp": "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com; PathPrefix:/foo; ReplacePathRegex:^/foo(.*) /bar$1"`

Comment: My bad : I forgot to add a "$" => you need to escape it with.. itself! I have corrected my answer. Here's an explanation about it : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution